# Can I Put Multiple Animations on a Single Skeletal Mesh?

Tags: animation, armature

I have a skeletal mesh I want to use in an Unreal Engine game, and I've made a running animation for it.

Is it possible to create multiple animations (e.g. attacking, resting, etc.), and store them all in the same skeletal mesh?

Should I put only a passive animation in blender, and then the create the other animations in Unreal?

Comment: what do you mean by "store them"? If you go in the Dope Sheet, you can switch from Dope Sheet/Dope Sheet mode to Dope Sheet/Action Editor mode, and create new actions or load old actions... I don't know how you import them in Unreal though

Comment: Also If you don't use the action in your scene don't forget to click on the little shield icon on the right of the action name, so that it doesn't get deleted when you close the file

Answer (score 0):

As Moonboots said, you have to turn a dopesheet window into an action editor and store every animation as an action, pressing the shield icon to enable the "fake user" function so that you won't loose your stored actions when the software is closed. Then, while exporting in Fbx format you have to enable the "all actions" option, so that the Fbx file will carry all the actions to UE.

[image]

[image]